# Sympy summation of a sequence

Tags: python, sequence, sympy

I have a simple sequence of values in Python `sympy`. I want to sum the values
of the sequence. I have come with a solution, but it is quite clumsy. 
Is there a way to do it more naturally?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sympy import summation, sequence, pprint
from sympy.abc import x

s = sequence(x, (x, 1, 10))
print(s)
pprint(s)

print(summation(s.formula, (x, s.interval.left, s.interval.right)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/sequences.html#elementary-sequences), the items in a `SeqFormula`s can be enumerated with `list`:

```
In [53]: list(s)
Out[53]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

So the sum can be evaluated with

```
In [54]: sum(list(s))
Out[54]: 55
```

Of course, this will only work with finite sequences.

---

Another way to write the sum is:

```
In [115]: summation(s.formula, (x, s.start, s.stop))
Out[115]: 55
```

Comment: Is there a way/syntax to use a sequence in summation, product differently? I would expect `summation(seq)` to work right away.

Comment: `summation` requires that you specify the limits of the summation. You could use `summation(s.formula, (x, s.start, s.stop))` in that case.